# free flv player

Tags: flash

I'm looking for a free flash player so that I can **stream** flv files on my website (like youtube). Anybody know of any good and free solution with no watermark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Toobplayer](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/lightweight-flv-player-component-toobplayer/) is cool. Free - very good. But it is AS2. but is does come with a component! wwe use it at work.

### Update:

here are many freebies out there to assist you in getting a video player made.

- http://flowplayer.org/ - popular, but charges for the good stuff.
- http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/ this is JWplayer and you may have seen it in many places.
- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/lightweight-flv-player-component-toobplayer/ easy to use but is AS2
- But I recommend http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/ This has been strongly developed within the towers of Adobe and theres nothing you cannot do with it. It's AS3 and free of charge. You can see examples of this on Adobes' Dev Net or Brimlows blog.

I use it myself and it includes many examples, embed code, documentation and feature plugins such as youtube and adverts.

Comment: Good wrapup and list.  Here are details regarding his original requirements:

Flowplayer - has watermark, pay to remove
Longtail JW PLayer - has watermark, pay to remove
ToobPlayer - need Flash editing skillz
OpenSourceMediaFramework - need Flash editing skills

Answer (score 2):

[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) is a known flv free player

Comment: Flowplayer has a good support forum/community, the reason I don't like it is because it uses Quicktime as a Flash fallback rather than HTML5 video tags.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/)

Comment: It's free for non-commercial use and the free version is branded with a JW Player logo. I'll warn anyone about to buy a license for this product that the technical support is not good, I found that FlowPlayer has better technical support. The good thing about JW Player is that it uses Flash/HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one? - Even Opensource under BSD. http://www.gruposistemas.com/gsplayer/

Answer (score 1):

This one is the best.  All those others either

1. Have watermarks
2. Or you need Flash builder and Flash skills

Here's what you want: (MediaElement.js)[Media Element JS](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

It has no watermark, works will all browsers and mobile.
It comes with a Flash fallback SWF player so you don't have to make one.

Use Miro and Handbrake to convert your video to the needed formats and you are good to go.

Comment: The key to these working is also making sure your server has these new mime types added.  Without video type .mp4 added, you will run into strange non-working situations without any browser console errors - particularly in IE.  So confirm your server knows those file types.