# Videos for web page

Tags: javascript, html, video

Yesterday [I ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095179/video-flash-or-videos-for-html) about videos for websites, and I get response with several useful links that helped to understand how videos can be implemented to a web page. But now I get stuck. I don't know what to do.

People said that I need to use HTML5 with fallback (if no HTML5 supported than use own player). That's okay, but my web space is limited. I can't use 3 different file formats (ogg, mpeg, flv or swf) for only 1 video. So that's why I'm need to use flv.

I'm trying to make my own player, but I don't know where to start. I'm searching for 'video player tutorial html', 'video tutorial html', 'js player video tutorial' etc. but Google gives me 'Tutorial for beginners HTML' and that's useless for me, I don't find any link where to start.

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=create+your+own+video+player+html

Comment: fallback means to use flash player, not another video format

Comment: If you just want to use flv you need a flash flv player; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889646/free-flv-player all of which will come with samples/documentation

Comment: you should use a service like youtube or vimeo if you dont understand how to add a simple video tag to a webpage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-video/info

Comment: If you are limited to maximum one format, go for [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) format. It can be played inside latest versions of Adobe Flash player, iPots and some browsers (not all) using HTML5 `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. My web editors have no idea of how to create multiple formats of their videos...

Using the comments to your question I did this:

```
<embed height="280" type="" width="320" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="undefined" allowfullscreen="true" x-shockwave-flashallowscriptaccess="always" application="" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" flashvars="file=http://www.musikali.dk/media/1500/new_holland_vs_john_deere.mp4" />
```

I did it as a macro for the Umbraco CMS using this as a part of an xslt, that handles multiple filetypes

```
<xsl:if test="contains(macro/Media1/File/umbracoFile, '.mp4')"> 
  <embed  height="280" type="" width="320" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="undefined"  allowfullscreen="true" x-shockwave-flashallowscriptaccess="always"  application="" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf">
  <xsl:attribute name="flashvars">file=http://www.musikali.dk<xsl:value-of  select="macro/Media1/File/umbracoFile"/></xsl:attribute>
  </embed>
</xsl:if>
```

...so its NOT html5, but allows my editors to only use one filetype.

Answer (score 1):

Search harder and use the right keywords. Something like "html5 video" should get you results. HTML5 keyword specifies that you're specifically looking for html5 related ones.

http://html5video.org/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/